# Is it sensible to manage one codebase with both git and TFS?

Tags: git, version-control, tfs

I would like to be able to work on a bit of code in the office and then go home and pick it up where I left off. As we use TFS I invariably have to work on my work machine over RDP. This is sub-optimal but necessary as I have never been able to get along with TFS' *shelvesets* so shelving my changes before I go home isn't an option and obviously I can't check incomplete code into the main repository (we are branch-averse in TFS so work in just `dev` and `main` branches). At some point in the not-too-distant future we're switching to git. But until then, I have to work.

I thought I could check out from TFS into a codebase that was also managed by git. Then at the end of the day/week i could check my interim changes, complete with bugs, into git (offsite) ready to pull down and work on at home on my own machines. When I'm done working on something I check first into git and then into TFS.

Has anyone got experience of this and if so, would you recommend it?

Comment: I do not get why Git can help, if you must RDP on a machine to work.
If you work on a remote machine, why not checkin-in code?

Comment: I RDP onto the work machine because my working context (files, workspaces etc.) is maintained on it. The alternative would have me check-in in my changes, go home, check my changes out, work on the code then check it all in ready for when i'm back in the office. But of course if i start checking in incomplete code it will affect my colleagues.

Comment: I read between the lines that your team expects "big commits" with full fledged features, while you prefer to experiment code alternatives and would like to have your private "nested" version control system. Shelvesets are not good, because they are just named snapshot with no historical depth.

Is this your scenario?

Comment: Yes. I just need to be able to safely mark my position at work, restore it on a different machine and pick up where I left off. So I just need a snapshot (or a diff between my last check-in and now) .

Comment: Which is what Shelveset are for! What's your problem with those?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an overly complex way to avoid using shelvesets.

If you want to make it work:

- Using [git-tf](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) or [git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com/), create a local git repo on your work machine synced with the TFS server.
- Add a remote to the work machine's git repo connected to your offsite git server (i.e. GitHub or Visual Studio Online for example)
- On Friday, add your unfinished changes to a branch, and push that to the VSO/GH repo.
- On your home machine you can then fetch the changes from the VSO/GH repo to your local repo, make changes in your work-in-progress branch and then push them back to VSO/GH.
- At work, on Monday morning, pull the changes from the VSO/GH repo onto your work machine's git repo, finished whatever you need to, merge with the main/dev code and then push that back into TFS.

It's an ugly workaround to avoid using a feature TFS has had for ages, but it's viable.

You'll also need to make sure work doesn't mind that their source code is now on a server outside of their network, but that's up to you to sort out.

Comment: I wish shelvesets worked for me - last time I used them I wasn't actually able to even see them despite them apparently going in without errors.